# Transform Logical Data model to SQL Table design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

In a LDM I recently made, I have an entity which has the following structure:

```
Building_ID (Primary Key, Foreign Key),
Plant_ID (Foreign Key),
Build_Year (Primary Key),
Size
```

I need to create a table in a SQL database using this design. The question I'm running into is how do I handle the primary keys here? Is it OK for a SQL table to have multiple primary keys? If the answer to this question is yes, then which column should act as the unique index? Should I create a new column to act as the unique index identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SQL table for any relational database system (SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird, IBM DB2, Sybase etc.) I know can only ever have **one** primary key - after all, it's the **primary** key - there can only ever be one.

However, a primary key can be made up from multiple columns (called a "compound primary key"). There are downsides such as: all foreign key constraints from other tables also must specify **all** columns in the compound PK, thus making joining the tables a bit of a pain (since you need to specify all equality constraints for all columns included in the key in your JOIN).

Besides a primary key, you can also have multiple **alternate keys** - other column(s) that could also identify the row uniquely. Those make excellent candidates for e.g. indices, if those can help you speed up access to the table (but don't over-index your tables! Less is more)

Comment: Thanks for the information, Marc. So would you suggest that I create a new primary key (in this case I would make Building_ID the primary key) and remove the primary key constraint from "build_year"?

Comment: @Evan: is `Building_ID` on its own guaranteed to be NOT NULL and unique for each row? Then yes - that makes a perfect primary key. And there's **no point** in adding additional columns into the primary key if that one column alone does the job of uniquely and reliably identifying each row in the table

Comment: the problem is that `Building_ID` is also a foreign key to another entity `Building`. The only primary key above that is *not* also a foreign key to another table is `Build_Year` - but let's face it, that is in no way guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @evan: whether or not that's a FK into another table is **irrelevant** - the only question is: is it **NOT NULL** and does it **uniquely and reliably** identify each row in the table?? If yes --> it's your primary key; if no --> keep looking